# email field not saving in admin site

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

When I try the following code in django 2.1 the email field is not saving in the admin site.only the username is saving.I can create emailfield in Custom form.So can anyone help me to sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance

views.py
'''

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Enter Username', min_length=4, max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Enter email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Enter password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['username'],
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password1']
        )
        return user
```

'''
forms.py
'''

```
from django.forms import EmailField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = EmailField(required=True)


    class meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.In the forms.py we want to use the capital m for meta class instead of using small m.it was the error